# MongoDB updating the wrong subdocument in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I've recently started using MongoDB using Mongoose (from NodeJS), but now I got stuck updating a subdocument in an array.
Let me show you...

I've set up my Restaurant in MongoDB like so:

```
_id: ObjectId("5edaaed8d8609c2c47fd6582")
name: "Some name"
tables: Array
  0: Object
    id: ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b60")
    status: "AVAILABLE"
  1: Object
    id: ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b61")
    status: "AVAILABLE"
```

As you can see a restaurant can have multiple tables, obviously.
Now I would like to update the status of a table for which I know the _id. I also know the _id of the restaurant that has the table.
But....I only want to update the status if we have the corresponding tableId and this table has the status 'AVAILABLE'.

My update statement:

```
const result = await Restaurant.updateOne(
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5edaaed8d8609c2c47fd6582"), 
    'tables._id': ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b61"), 
    'tables.status': 'AVAILABLE' 
  },
  { $set: { 'tables.$.status': 'CONFIRMED' } }
);
```

Guess what happens when I run the update-statement above?
It strangely updates the FIRST table (with the wrong table._id)!
However, when I remove the 'tables.status' filter from the query, it does update the right table:

```
const result = await Restaurant.updateOne(
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5edaaed8d8609c2c47fd6582"), 
    'tables._id': ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b61")
  },
  { $set: { 'tables.$.status': 'CONFIRMED' } }
);
```

Problem here is that I need the status to be 'AVAILABLE', or else it should not update!
Can anybody point me in the wright direction with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docs, the [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document

so you are updating only the first array element in the document that matches your query

you should use the [filtered positional operator $[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

so your query will be something like that

```
const result = await Restaurant.updateOne(
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5edaaed8d8609c2c47fd6582"),
    'tables._id': ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b61"),
    'tables.status': 'AVAILABLE'
  },
  {
    $set: { 'tables.$[table].status': 'CONFIRMED' } // update part
  },
  { 
    arrayFilters: [{ "table._id": ObjectId("5ee277bab0df345e54614b61"), 'table.status': 'AVAILABLE' }] // options part
  }
);
```

by this way, you're updating the table element that has that `tableId` and `status`

hope it helps

Comment: sorry there was something not correct in my answer, I've updated my answer, could you check it now?

Comment: "so you are updating only the first array element in the document that matches your query"

Well...that's actually what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't seem to be correct.
My query now exists of 2 parts (tableId & status), but it's not looking for a combination of those two....

Comment: My question is...WHY is it matching the first array element?

Comment: if the tables array has the following elements `[{_id: 'tableId1, status: 'Available'}, {_id: 'tableId2, status: 'Available'}]`, If you just do a find query (not update), all the array elements will be returned in the query, as in `mongoDB`, the search is done in the documents level, not in the array level, so the whole array will be returned in the document, then if you want to update the table that has `_id: 'tableId2'`, and you are using the `$ operator`, you will update the table element that has `_id='tableId1'` by mistake as the `$ updates` the first element in the array

Comment: that's why we need to use the arrayFilters part, to update the element in the array that matches our needs

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Just updated the code...and it's working like a charm!!